# Maximum number of child processes created by this code fragment

Tags: unix, fork

What is the maximum number of child processes created by the code fragment below, that coexist simultaneously.

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    if (fork()==0) {
        sleep(2);
        exit(0);
    }
    if (i%2==0) {
        wait(0);
    }
}
wait(0);
wait(0);
```

My first answer was 2 processes but I don't know if parent creates process at line 2.

Comment: Why don't you run it, perhaps with a printf statement or two, and see for yourself?  Come back to us if you have problems with the compilation or understanding the behavior.

Comment: You don't know if parent creates process at line 2? What else do you think `fork()` does?

Comment: I suggest you draw a timeline on a piece of paper, showing what each process does every second.